# How to disable network for a running Docker container?

Tags: docker

I would like to start a Docker container normally, run it, install some things into it, and then I would like to disable the network, to run some more commands in it, but they should not have access to the network. How can I do that for a running container?

I use [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) and I know I can use `network_disabled` to disable networking for the whole container. But I am not sure how I can disable the network after the container is already created. Ideally, I would run the container with command `sleep infinity`, then `docker exec` some commands in it, then disable networking, then run few more commands using `docker exec`.

Comment: Do you want the container to not have access to the internet, or to other containers, or both?

Comment: Internet mostly. I do not care about other containers. I mean, there are no other containers connected to it at any point. So dropping all networking is fine.

Comment: Why do you need to run commands after the container is started, instead of committing the output of such commands into an image? Are you doing some update that really must be done as the container starts and can't be done once and forever?

Comment: It is run inside a CI with dynamic commands to test things. I could be creating an image with those initial commands, but that image would then be thrown away immediately after the second batch of commands. So I wonder if there is an easier way.

Comment: Yes, create the image in another CI process, push the image to a registry, and then pull your custom image in the original CI.

Comment: I really do not want to preserve that image at all.

Comment: You can build it in your CI system every time, but sometimes building an image is slow enough that pulling it will be faster. Generally, it is a good idea to build CI so it runs quickly.

Comment: The commands to run in the base image are different with every CI run. There is no point in complicating with two CI runs and preserving the image. Commands are part of what is being tested inside CI. One set of commands prepare stuff, another set of commands test stuff (but should not have network access so that CI fails if network access is attempted by mistake).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe an option would be [docker network disconnect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_disconnect/)

> ### Description
>
> Disconnect a container from a network
>
> ### Usage
>
> ```
> docker network disconnect [OPTIONS] NETWORK CONTAINER
> ```

**Example:**

Create a container attached to the default bridge network

```
docker container run --rm -it alpine ping 8.8.8.8
```

and after a while disconnect it with:

```
docker network disconnect bridge <container-name>
```

[image]

Comment: If `docker network disconnect bridge <container-name>` doesn't work for you, try `docker network disconnect docker_default <container-name>`. To connect your container back, run: `docker network connect docker_default <container-name>`.

Answer (score 1):

The standard pattern you should use here is to write a Dockerfile that does whatever software installation you need, and builds an image out of it.  This actually fits your immediate need quite nicely, since once you've built the image you can run it without network.

A typical Dockerfile skeleton might look more or less like

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      thing-to-run-without-network
CMD ["/usr/bin/thing-to-run-without-network"]
```

And then you'd build and run it as

```
docker build -t no-net-test .
docker run --rm --net none no-net-test
```

Generally you should set your image up so that `docker run` does everything the container needs to do, without needing to `docker exec` ever (except for hand debugging).  You should never install things into a running container: your work will get lost as soon as you `docker rm` the container, and deleting and restarting your containers is extremely routine.

Comment: Yes, in my case I am OK with things being lost, because all those commands are run (and generated dynamically) during CI run. So this is why creating an image just to run commands and then erase everything sounds a bit too much and I wonder if there is a simpler way to just drop the networking during container run.